# Error - Executions on HTTP endpoints are disabled. Set enableHttpEndpoints to true in manifest file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-console, google-workspace-add-ons

In a Google Apps Script, I'm trying to use a Cloud Function URL as described [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/alternate-runtimes-quickstart#step_3_create_an_add-on_deployment)

But I'm getting an error:

> Executions on HTTP endpoints are disabled. Set enableHttpEndpoints to true in manifest file.

I've searched all over Google's documentation, stack overflow, and google and can't figure out where to put that `enableHttpEndpoints: true`. Anywhere I've tried results in an invalid manifest error.

[image: error]

[image]

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "name",
      "logoUrl": "logo",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "firebase functions URL here"
      },
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the same behavior using all the prefix as `https://`?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this one out. You can't use the "classic" Google Apps Script editor to deploy an addon that uses HTTP endpoints (aka Alternate Runtime).

Instead you have to go to the Google Cloud Console and enable the Alternate Runtime feature of the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK service.

This URL should take your straight there: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk_gsao

Once enabled, you create a deployment on the same page using the button `Create New Deployment`. It appears that you don't need to use the "classic" Apps Script editor at all (which is great!). The schema doesn't seem 100% compatible so please correct any validation warnings before submitting.

Once a deployment has been created you can simply click `Install` next to it to test it out.

That's about as far as I've gotten. My addon finally hit my endpoint.

More information here: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention to any `enableHttpEndpoints` in the documentation (which can be read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons)), nor there seems to be any response to the call. This is an issue that has been reported in Issue Tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/214015254

You can click the star next to the issue number to upvote it and give it more visibility.

Meanwhile, I would suggest using endpoints with an `https://` prefix, as it is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests#allowlist_urls) that `http://` endpoints are not accepted.